# Error invoking the "Endpoints.cmd" to generate the client library bundle

Tags: java, android, windows, google-app-engine

I'm trying to create the library of my backend project on Google Cloud to export it in an Android project. I'm following this guide:

[https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android#adding_the_client_library_to_the_project](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/endpoints_tool#generating_a_client_library_bundle_from_a_backend_api)

This is what I wrote in cmd (as the guide said):

```
endpoints.cmd get-client-lib --war=<project-WAR-directory> -bs gradle com.app.example
```

but I got into this error:

```
INFO: Successfully processed <my_project_path>\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Error: com.app.example
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: 1. Are you building your appengine project with gradle? 2. Is your backend project part of your larger android project?

Comment: 1) What I want to do is create a library from my backend, and I'm trying to use gradle (as the guide sais);
2) No, I'm at the beginning of the creation of a project that needs a backend. And yes, I want to create an Android project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want to use the endpoints.cmd directly (you need to include the full path to your endpoint class, not the packageName):

```
endpoints.cmd get-client-lib --war=<wardir> -bs gradle com.app.fqn.EndpointClass
```

I believe that's why you're getting that error at the end

Alternatively if you're using android studio with appengine/endpoints, you might try the guide here : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates

If you're using gradle for a stand alone appengine project and just want to generate client library you can try some of the endpoints gradle commands (from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin#tasks).

`gradle appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs` (will download the zip)
`gradle appengineEndpointsExportClientLibraries` (will download and jar the client libs)
`gradle appengineEndpointsInstallClientLibraries` (will download, package and install to local maven repo)